# redux-thunk repeat redux-api-middlware action until timeout or state variable set

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

I have an endpoint the can be polled by a GET request and it returns if a task has finished.
`{"status":"running"}`
or
`{"status":"completed"}`
I am using redux-api-middleware to create the actions that make the api call.

```
export const TASK_REQUEST = '@@unshorten/TASK_REQUEST';
export const TASK_SUCCESS = '@@unshorten/TASK_SUCCESS';
export const TASK_FAILURE = '@@unshorten/TASK_FAILURE';


export const check_task = (hash) => ({
 [RSAA]: {
    endpoint: '/api/task_status/'+hash+'/',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: withAuth({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }), 
      types: [
        {   
          type:RASTERIZE_REQUEST, 
          meta:{hash:hash}
        },  
        {   
          type:RASTERIZE_SUCCESS, 
          meta:{hash:hash}
        },  
        {   
          type:RASTERIZE_FAILURE, 
          meta:{hash:hash}
        },  
      ]   
  }

})
```

I need to keep calling this action and wait 20 seconds between calls until the endpoint returns `{"status":"completed"}` or the max timeout of say 120 seconds is reached.

My proposed solution is to use a redux thunk with an async wait for 20 seconds that calls the above action repeatedly until the returned status is completed or the timeout is reached.

I will need to a store like so for the above part:

```
{
initial_call_time:1,
last_call_time:12,
status:'running'
}
```

This way I could check the store variables on the next few calls to see if time has expired or status is completed

Is there a better solution to handle this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Redux Saga is the best polling framework I have found.  Here is a good tutorial that is exactly describing the situation I am trying to solve.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/keep-calm-and-race-on-redux-saga-case-study-2f5b0a6630ae